# When using JUnit5, I got a warning: "ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.engine.support.filter.ExclusionReasonConsumingFilter"

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I'm trying to use JUnit5.
First, I added dependencies to maven project:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then, I created a test:

```
package com.example.multicurrency;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class JunitTests {
    @Test
    void testAssertTrue() {
        assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

After that, I run the test. The following is what I have got:

```
org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
warning: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/support/filter/ExclusionReasonConsumingFilter
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.engine.support.filter.ExclusionReasonConsumingFilter

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :<true> 
Actual   :<false>
```

The result was what I expected. But the warning confused me. What does the warning mean?

Comment: It seems, as you don't want JUnit 4 tests in your project. If yes, please remove the dependency to `junit-platform-runner` ... it is only need to launch the JUnit Platform via a JUnit 4 runner. See details at https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-junit-platform-runner

Comment: @Sormuras Thank you. I removed juinit-platform-runner and it does worked. But then I find updating my intellij idea can also solve my problem.

Answer (score 24):

Use version `5.3.x` of the `junit-jupiter-engine` for now with Surefire `2.22.2`.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Seems like you're struck by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1564 which describes a known issue that Surefire `2.22.0` internally stays on version `1.2.0` for all `junit-platfrom-xyz` artifacts.

You should also give Surefire 3.x a try - afaik, it is compatible with all versions of JUnit: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/

Comment: Downgrading from 5.5.2 to 5.3.2 fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Added above: "You should also give Surefire 3.x a try - afaik, it is compatible with all versions of JUnit: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/"

Answer (score 0):

1. When you add JUNIT5 dependency, it automatically contains "junit-platform-engine" and "junit-jupiter-api". You can check this in Dependency Heirarchy of "Pom.xml". so you can remove other dependecies you added along with JUNIT5. Just JUNIT5 dependency is sufficient.
2. Also make sure there are no references to JUNIT4 dependencies. If you are trying to use mix of JUNIT and JUNT5 such warning may occur because you are tricking JVM.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).